# Как на странице загружать JSON файл и выводить его на HTML странице без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Есть некий динамически изменяемый с периодичностью около 1 секунды JSON файл. Количество пар ключ-значение не постоянное.

```
    {
        "stage": "Video Extract",
        "current_iter": "287",
        "max_iter": "4087"
}
```

Стоит задача читать из файла данные с периодичностью 1 секунда и отображать информацию на HTML странице без ее перезагрузки или без кликов по кнопкам. Каждый ключ отображать между

.
Надо AJAX использовать, вроде, но я совсем не JS программист. Как это реализовать?

Comment: JSON, который обновляется каждую секунду? Звучит как сюр, там точно не сокеты?

Comment: Могу предложить поискать на этом ресурсе варианты [ru.stackoverflow.com/search](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+JSON+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+HTML). В кратце, да, вам надо ajax'ом(fetch или axios) обращаться за файлом, парсить его, а далее отрисовывать в HTML. Если ключи разные, то скорее всего надо будет использовать цикл. Для организации постоянного запроса на сервер нужен будет ``setInterval``